# "Scroll Up" functionality is not behaving as expected in React Native WebView

Tags: stripe-payments, react-native-webview

In my project, we load the shopping site into the WebView, and the site loads without any issues. The problem arises when there is a textbox at the bottom of the screen on the shopping site. When I click or tap on it, the keyboard hides the text, and it does not automatically scroll up.

However, when using the same shopping URL in an external browser like Chrome, it automatically scrolls up when hitting the textbox.

Environment:

"react": "17.0.2",

"react-native": "0.65.3",

"react-native-webview": "^13.2.2",

[Example image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoAgk.jpg)
[Example image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKDX0.jpg)

Comment: It's generally discouraged to use Webview in your mobile apps due to hard debugging and unpredictable behaviors. Instead, consider using the Stripe react native SDK. It offers smoother integration and fewer unexpected behaviors. Here's a handy guide to get you started:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We didn't use any payment methods and don't plan to in the future. We are only loading a shopping site into the webview.